# Can we remove the ability to login using a username for community members, and only include the ability to login using KP Single Sign-on?

Tags: single-sign-on

Can we remove the ability to login using a username for community members, and only include the ability to login using KP Single Sign-on?

[image: Can we able to hide the possibilty of entering username and password as shown in second image]

[image: When the user access the link it should be as per the second image so they can use single sign -on]

Comment: In communities workspaces -->Administration did you unselect everything except for  KP in the login options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to disable the Username/Password login and Select SSO as login method for community on community workspace. Setup -> All communities -> Your Community Workspace -> Administration -> Login and Registration -> Login Options. 
Make sure SAML is enabled under Single Sign-On settings and SSO is configured properly, otherwise SSO Option won't be available for Login.
Help link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_page.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null